# Creating Android App builds

Tags: android, android-build

How do I create Android app builds similar to Windows code builds? I have my Android app code base checked in to Tortoise SVN. But I also have the binaries checked in - i.e the apk file etc. and not just the source code. Everytime there is a change I am building it manually on Eclipse and then updating the apk and the code folders. Is there no mechanism to create builds like on Windows where you run a batch file running the visual studio exe to create builds and binaries. I need this because otherwise it s just replacing the apk's everytime. Its very frustrating that I dont know this simple detail so please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ant building scripts (details at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to just checkin your project to SVN. The other team member or even you when loading it in another working space (another PC or diff Eclipse WorkSpace), Eclipse will throw error.

Simply clean the project it should rebuild the app and APK files for you again. Nothing much to worry. Me and my friends have done it several times.

Correct me if I'm wrong.